# If Statement depending on the contents of a .txt file - Python 3.9

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.9, txt

```
def change():
    wind = Tk()...
    text1 = Entry(wind)
    text1.pack()

    def write():
        newfile = open("newfile.txt", "w")
        newfile.write(text1.get())
        newfile.close()

    def show_password():
        global r1
        r1 = open("newfile.txt", "r")
        print("Password is: %s" % r1.read())

    btn2 = Button(wind, text="Show Password", command=show_password)
    btn2.pack(pady=5)

    btn1 = Button(wind, text="Set Password", command=write)
    btn1.pack(pady=5)


def dark():
    pop = Tk()...

    e1 = Entry(pop, background="#292929", foreground="white")
    e1.place(x=60, y=0)
    e2 = Entry(pop, background="#292929", foreground="white")
    e2.place(x=60, y=22)

    def login():
        global no1
        username = (e1.get())
        password = (e2.get())
        print("Username: %s\nPassword: %s" % (e1.get(), e2.get()))
        if username == "a" and password == r1.read():
            new_win = Tk()... 
        elif username == "a" and password != r1.read():
            sleep(5)

mainloop()
```

Whenever I run the program, I don't get an error message. However, when I type in what I have just set or set before as the password (in the txt file) or what is printed in the terminal, it sleeps the program like I got it wrong. I've posted this before and it was too long, so it's shortened now. This is just revision for my assessment.

Comment: There are multiple places where you do `r1.read()`. The first time you get the full content of the file. Then the file pointer is at the end of the file and when you try to read from the file again you get an empty string.

Comment: Read the file once into a variable, then compare with that variable each time.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you can do:

```
File = open(‘file.txt’, ‘r’)
File_context = File.read()
File.close()

If ‘Word’ in File_context:
    Print(‘FOUND!’)
```

Tell me if it works!

Comment: It works now! Thank you. My teacher said this will give me lots more marks in my assessment.

Comment: No problem! Hope you pass